# modinfo srcversion: How do I generate this from my source?

Tags: linux-kernel, module

I have a compiled version of a linux module, and then I have about 20+ variations of its source.  Through various foolish mistakes, I've lost track of which version of the source was the actual one I used to make the module.

I noticed that `modinfo <module name>` gives `srcversion: <hash>`, and I found some explanation somewhere that says its the "Sum of the source that produced the module".  Sounds perfect!

What do I do to my module sources to produce this hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `srcversion` is defined by the `scripts/mod/modpost` program. I don't know the exact options that you have to give to modpost so that it outputs this field. It must be something similar to `scripts/mod/modpost -a -m vmlinux you_module.o` (you can look at `scripts/Makefile.modpost` for the exact options). The output is then available in `drivers/path/to/your_module.mod.c`

I recommend that you set the `config MODULE_SRCVERSION_ALL` to y (available in the `Enable loadable module support` submenu), so that srcversion is automatically produced for all the modules of your build. You can then switch between you variations of the source, rebuild your kernel with the new source variation (only your module should be rebuilt after the first build) and then directly look at the `MODULE_INFO(srcversion, "<hash>");` field at the end of your `drivers/path/to/your_module.mod.c` file to find the requested info.