# What is the significance of THIS_MODULE in Linux kernel module drivers?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In Linux device driver development, the `file_operations` structure uses `struct module *owner`.

- What is the use of this structure when we always initialize it with `THIS_MODULE`?
- When can this field be set to `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_operation` is one of the main structures that used to connect the device numbers and the file operations of a driver.

- There are lots of function pointer in the structure. The first pointer is `struct module *owner` which is not a function pointer at all but points to a structure module defined in the `<linux/module.h>`.
- On initializing to `THIS_MODULE`, it holds the ownership of the module.
- One of the main reasons to initialize `struct module *owner` to `THIS_MODULE` to prevent the module from getting unloaded while in use.

Comment: The kernel build system implicitely adds __this_module as symbol when building kernel module. So, the ownership of the cdev belongs to the given kernel module.

Answer (score 12):

This field tells who is owner of `struct file_operations`. This prevents module to get unloaded when it is in operation. When initialized with `THIS_MODULE` current module holds the ownership on it.

Answer (score 7):

**Minimal runnable example**

Whenever you create a kernel module, the kernel's build machinery generates a [`struct module`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.16/include/linux/module.h#L329) object for you, and makes `THIS_MODULE` point to it.

This struct contains many fields, some of which can be set with module macros such as `MODULE_VERSION`.

This example shows how to access that information: `module_info.c`:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int myinit(void)
{
    /* Set by default based on the module file name. */
    pr_info("name    = %s\n", THIS_MODULE->name);
    pr_info("version = %s\n", THIS_MODULE->version);
    return 0;
}

static void myexit(void) {}

module_init(myinit)
module_exit(myexit)
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Dmesg outputs:

```
name    = module_info
version = 1.0
```

Some `MODULE_INFO` fields can also be "accessed" in the following ways:

- `cat /sys/module/module_info/version`
- `modinfo /module_info.ko | grep -E '^version:'`

Since the address of that `struct module` object must be unique across all modules, it serves as a good argument for `fops.owner` as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468893/895245. Here is [a minimal example of that usage](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/d992ba4e6e87fe7a2de1def3eb808649277f2ed7/kernel_module/fops.c#L134).

Tested in Linux kernel 4.16 with [this QEMU + Buildroot setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/d992ba4e6e87fe7a2de1def3eb808649277f2ed7/kernel_module/module_info.c).

Answer (score 4):

[1] **struct module *owner** is commonly used at some structures and is not an operation at all; it is a pointer to the module that "owns"the structure. This field is used to prevent the module from being unloaded while its operations are in use. Almost all the time, it is simply initialized to *THIS_MODULE*, a macro defined in 
 *< linux/module.h>* .

.

[2] I would not recommend you to set it to null, because it may lead to driver malfunction and other problems. Instead, use the good practices of linux kernel development.

In some architectures the ***".owner"*** was removed, so, make sure your distro and architecture still using it.

I hope it helps your understanding.

*References: LDD3, kernel newbies.*